# Valgrind unhandled instruction bytes error

Tags: valgrind

In order to search for memory leaks in my application based on the Liv555 library, I tried to run it using valgrind. It results in the following error:

```
vex amd64->IR: unhandled instruction bytes: 0xC5 0xF9 0x57 0xC0 0xC5 0xFA 0x10 0x15
```

Running it on another computer does not result in this error (it runs just fine), so I expect this to be the result of some library version. Could this be the problem? If so, does anyone know which library could be causing the error? 
The output of `valgrind` with the `-v -v` options is located [here](http://www.tym.nl/valgrind_output.txt).

Comment: There is a similar bug in Valgrind Bugzilla - [http://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=280835](http://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=280835)

Comment: Adding, say, `-msse2` or `-msse3` to `CFLAGS` or `CXXFLAGS` should help isolate the issue. If it goes away, then its likely the result of Valgrind not understanding the latest SSE instructions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here the [FAQ](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/faq.html)  with exact explanation.

Search for "vex x86->IR: unhandled instruction bytes"

Here the issue:

Looks like you've using binary (/usr/lib/libFLAC.so.8.2.0) compiled with intel SSE4 optimization (strncmp_sse42) which is not supported on amd you've using (Arch and hwcaps: AMD64, amd64-sse3-cx16).

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue on CentOS 7:

```
vex amd64->IR: unhandled instruction bytes: 0xF 0xAE 0x64 0x24 0x40 0x48 0x8B 0x73
vex amd64->IR:   REX=0 REX.W=0 REX.R=0 REX.X=0 REX.B=0
vex amd64->IR:   VEX=0 VEX.L=0 VEX.nVVVV=0x0 ESC=0F
vex amd64->IR:   PFX.66=0 PFX.F2=0 PFX.F3=0
==10527== valgrind: Unrecognised instruction at address 0x4016b18.
==10527==    at 0x4016B18: _dl_runtime_resolve_xsave (in /usr/lib64/ld-2.17.so)
```

The solution was to install the kernel debug info.

```
yum --enablerepo=base-debuginfo install -y kernel-debuginfo-$(uname -r)
```